# Pandas dataframe filter rows in condition but keep empty cells

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter out some rows by a condition value:

```
_a = my_df[my_df['A'] < 0.01]
```

But it also filters out rows with empty values. What I want is to filter rows that satisfy that condition and also keep empty values.

I am trying this but returns 0 rows. What I am doing wrong?

```
_a = my_df[pd.isnull(my_df['A']) | my_df['A'] < 0.01]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There are missing parentheses for second condition, because priority of operators:

```
_a = my_df[pd.isnull(my_df['A']) | (my_df['A'] < 0.01)]
```

Or use [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html):

```
_a = my_df[pd.isnull(my_df['A']) | my_df['A'].lt(0.01)]
```

Comment: oh my... thank you! How is this possible? Pandas is unable to interpret the operands of the conditions without parentheses?

Comment: @P.Solar - If chain condition then not.